# Export workflow rules into excel

Tags: workflow

I have a project where I need to document all Cases workflows and associated actions.How to export workflow rules including criteria and workflow actions into excel file.

Answer (score 2):

You can export validation rules and workflow rules by this tool [https://github.com/xjsender/SublimeApex (https://github.com/xjsender/SublimeApex" target="_blank)]

Comment: You can check this link for instructions

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gxvwAAA

Answer (score 2):

`SublimeApex` is renamed to `HaoIDE`, you can reach it at [HaoIDE](https://github.com/xjsender/haoide)